# Jquery smooth scroll with mousewheel effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

When my page first loads, I have a fullscreen jumbotron. When the user  goes to scroll down with the mousewheel I want to use the Jquery animate effect to bring the navbar (underneath the jumbotron) to the top of the page. 
I already have a button that can achieve this but I would like to do it with the mousewheel too.

How can i achieve this?
Thank you

```
    <!-- Jumobtron-->
    <div class="jumbotron" style="height: 100vh;">
        <a href="#mainNavbar">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnToNav">To Navbar</button>
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top" id="mainNavbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand"> Brand </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnToNav').on('click', function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#mainNavbar").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 
`mousewheel`  OR `DOMMouseScroll`

If you want to run that function in Firefox as well, you should use both of them, since Firefox doesn't have `mousewheel`, but they have `DOMMouseScroll`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnToNav').on('click', function(event){ 
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#mainNavbar").offset().top
      }, 1000);
    });
    
    $('html, body').on('mousewheel', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var delta = event.wheelDelta;
      if(delta < 0){
        // scroll from top to bottom
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#brand").offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }else{
        // scroll from bottom to top
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#btnToNav").offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Jumobtron-->
<div class="jumbotron" style="height: 100vh;">
  <a href="#mainNavbar">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btnToNav">To Navbar</button>
  </a>
</div>

    <!-- Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar sticky-top" id="mainNavbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="brand" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand"> Brand </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```